# Xcode will not open "Required content for Platform Android is missing"

Tags: android, ios, xcode, spritebuilder

I was trying to get back into coding today, and encountered a super weird error when opening Xcode, which says

```
"Required content for Platform Android is missing"
"Please reinstall Xcode"
```

I did some digging, and realized that this must be an error coming from some third party software. I used to use Spritebuilder, and I recall a while back I was trying to install the "SBAndroid-Community" package, to publish to Android devices.

I then found this page on the Apple Developer Forums, which basically describes my problem perfectly

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47245

The solution is to "remove a folder associated with Spritebuilder ~Library/SBAndroid"

However I see no such folder. I've looked within the contents of Xcode, Spritebuilder, and across my entire mac to no avail.

- I have tried reinstalling Xcode - does not work.
- I have tried deleting Spritebuilder by moving it to trash, emptying,
  deleting Xcode by moving to trash, emptying, reinstalling, and I
  still get the exact same error.

It seems there is some framework embedded in Xcode that is causing it to fail, and reinstalling doesn't help.

Does anybody have any ideas on where to go next? I really have exhausted my knowledge on this subject, and I really just want to open Xcode and have a fresh start.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I did not know "~" was an alias for your home folder. I have now located the ~/Library folder, but there is not an /SBAndroid folder within it. Still have no idea what to do =(.

**Edit 2:** I found the /SBAndroid folder in the ~/Library folder located in my Macintosh HD directory! After deleting, Xcode now opens.

Comment: Have you checked if the folder you need to delete is hidden? See [this AD answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/143897/124013).

Comment: Alright so I did not know that "~" was an alias to your home folder. I found the ~/Library folder, but still not /SBAndroid folder! Still at a loss =(

Comment: Just to sanity check: you have turned on showing hidden files in Terminal using "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES" and the /SBAndroid folder still cannot be found?

Comment: See my answer, I finally figured it out. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! (Thanks in big part to Ali Beadle)

First off, I didn't know that ~/Library folder was hidden by default. Eventually I found that folder, but still could not find the /SBAndroid folder.

Finally, I did a spotlight search which included system files (easy to find out how to do this online). Sure enough, I saw the /SBAndroid folder!.

It turns out, though, that the /SBAndroid folder was located in the ~/Library folder of my Macintosh HD (not my user folder).

After deleting, my Xcode app now opens.

So happy to have figured this out, thanks =).